# Как обработать нажатие аппаратных кнопок в сервисе (службе)?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Обычное приложение/`activity` (`onKeydown`,`onKeyLongPress`) не подходит, так как может быть незапущено. Нужен обработчик в фоновом процессе.

Comment: Вниманию "закрывальщиков" - отличный вопрос, не надо пытаться закрыть вопрос, который вы не понимаете...

Answer (score 0):

1. Вообще, по идее это невозможно. По определению `Service` это нечто не имеющее UI - работающее строго в фоне, в отрыве от `Activity`, а слушание клавиатуры, это уже подразумевает под собой некий UI
2. Можно попробовать настроить [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService), который определяет глобальный слушатель клавиатуры (Accessibility - грубо говоря это специальный вид UI для людей с ограниченными возможностями) - если все сделать правильно, то вы получите слушатель клавиатуры в своем сервисе
3. По моему, начиная с 6-го Android можно спокойно слушать в сервисе кнопки громкости, делается через `VolumeProvider/VolumeProviderCompat`

Comment: по п.1 оно понятно, но иногда вот нужно, жаль, что придется реализовывать через костыли (п.2,3)